# Cannot install Python Imaging Library using pip

Tags: software-installation, python, pip

I'm attempting to install the Python Imaging Library on Ubuntu 15.10 by running `pip install PIL`. When I try and run that (or even `pip uninstall PIL`) I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in
<module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 357,
in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2394,
in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2108,
in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])   File
"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 74, in
<module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9,
in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 22, in
<module>
    import requests, six   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line
53, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py",
line 43, in <module>
    ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3: OpenSSL.SSL.SSLv3_METHOD, AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PROTOCOL_SSLv3
```

Can anyone suggest why I can't install or uninstall pip?

Comment: Did you do sudo pip or just pip?

Comment: @HeatherBrown both and still get the same result

Comment: Try reinstalling pip with sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-pip

Answer (score 1):

There is a new fork of PIL called [Pillow](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pillow), you can install it by typing :

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-imaging
sudo apt-get install libjpeg8 libjpeg62-dev libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev
sudo pip install Pillow
```

You can see the [Official Documentation page](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/installation.html) for more informations.

To verify the version, just type :

```
>>> import PIL
>>> PIL.VERSION
'x.x.x'
```

`x.x.x` is the version number

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to install PIL, not a fork of it.